# How can I run a batch file silently?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, silent

I have a batch file with some commands that I need to run with my installer, but I'd rather a console not appear (in Windows). I'm executing the batch file from a WiX installer, via a custom action. I tried adding an `@ECHO OFF` to the top of the file, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way that I can run this batch file silently?

Comment: what do you mean pop up with the installer?

Comment: What do you mean? Please give us more detail.

Comment: He probably means he does not want to see the terminal (console) window during installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it with stdoutout redirect to file eg. `./script > x.txt`

Comment: Or redirect into Nirvana using `./script.bat > NUL` (The null device of Windows similar to /dev/null)

Comment: @0xa3: Why similar? Isn't it actually the same?

Comment: @Johannes Rössl: Sure, the concept is the same, just name and OS are different.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut to your batch file, then edit its properties, and select the run minimized option.